# Calling Custom Apache Velocity EventHandler Error

Tags: java, velocity

So I'm working to create a custom EventHandler to HTML escape (and more) variables and parameters across my website within Apache Velocity. I've tried using the default escape tools (EscapeHtmlReference, EscapeSqlReference, etc) but they where not suiting all of my needs.

So I created my own EventHandler based upon org.apache.velocity.app.event.implement.EscapeSqlReference but every time I try to call it I get a casting error.

The new class I created:

```
public class EscapeXmlPlusReference extends EscapeReference
{

/**
 * Escape all XML entities plus ;.
 *
 * @param text
 * @return An escaped String.
 * @see <a href="http://jakarta.apache.org/commons/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeSql(java.lang.String)">StringEscapeUtils</a>
 */
protected String escape(Object text)
{
    return StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(text.toString().replace(";",""));
}

/**
 * @return attribute "eventhandler.escape.xmlplus.match"
 */
protected String getMatchAttribute()
{
    return "eventhandler.escape.xmlplus.match";
}

}
```

My velocity.properties file

```
eventhandler.referenceinsertion.class = gov.location.of.class.security.vtool.EscapeXmlPlusReference
eventhandler.escape.xmlplus.match = /params.*/
```

But every time I load a page I get a cast exception

```
Velocity  [error] Could not initialize VelocityEngine - java.lang.ClassCastException: gov.location.of.class.security.vtool.EscapeXmlPlusReference cannot be cast to org.apache.velocity.app.event.EventHandler
```

Is there something small I am missing?

Comment: Looks like classloading issue was involved here. Maybe there were several copies of velocity in classpath.